# Sync blockchain while mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, synchronization, ethminer

I'm new to ether mining.

Do I have to sync with the blockchain while mining?

Currently I'm using ethminer for solo mining with GPU and geth to sync with blockchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [CPU Mining with Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/mining):

> Note that mining for real ether only makes sense if you are in sync with the network (since you mine on top of the consensus block). Therefore the eth blockchain downloader/synchroniser will delay mining until syncing is complete, and after that mining automatically starts unless you cancel your intention with miner.stop().

Once synced and mining commences, `geth` will keep the blockchain in sync while it hands off work packages to `ethminer` for `ethminer` to perform the mining computations.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you mine solo or not.

If you mine solo yes as @BokkyPooBah explained well you need to get geth synced.

If you mine on a pool ethminer should be enough.