# Finding eth balance within geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, synchronization, myetherwallet

I'm pretty new to mining, but I hope someone can help me.

when I use `eth.syncing`, I get this result:

```
 currentBlock: 1,
 highestBlock: 4884563,
 knownStates: 42878500,
 pulledStates: 42868030,
 StartingBlock: 4882867
}
```

Am I mining correctly?

When I type `web3.fromwei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")`,
it says:

`5`

But when I enter MEW with the key, there is not 5 ether in there?

Comment: Have you checked that the address viewed in MEW and  `eth.coinbase` are the same?

Comment: You are still syncing, you will not be able to mine until it has finished https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4080/sync-blockchain-while-mining

Comment: You should use     web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")

Answer (score 0):

The code has typo. Please use code below it worked for me.

```
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
```